# Two Forms on one page, With ajax submit functionality, _token is missing in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel

I've two different forms on one page. one accept the registration number to display user information with ajax.

The other one saves the information on another table with additional data. Now the problem is both forms have same _token value. So once the ajax form is submitted that _token is used so when I save other form I got _token error.

I'm using **Form::open()** and **Form::close()** for both forms.

What should I do?

**Here is my jQuery Code:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
        }
});

$('#payment_schedule').change(function(event) {
    var planId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::to('/PlanInfo') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {'paymentSchedule': planId},
        success: function(result){
            console.log("data = "+ result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status,response){
            $('#data').html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

});
 var inputs = $('#data input, #data select').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('#paymentForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = '{{ URL::to('/memberInfo') }}';
    var reg_no = $('#registration_no').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {'registration_no': reg_no},
        success: function(result){
            console.log('Ok'); //working fine
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

[image: Selecting Payment Plan]

**On Changing Payment Plan Receiving this error**

[image: On Changing Payment Plan Receiving this error]

Comment: try `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: in your script `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Answer (score 0):

create another view called form2, and then in the first view create a section with @yield('form2') and call the form2 with @section('form2') and close it with @endsection, like this 
put this in the first view

```
<form>
token1{{ csrf_field() }}
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
</form>
@yield('form2')
```

the in the second view put the other form like this

```
@section('form2')
<form>
token2{{ csrf_field() }}
blablabla
</form>
@endsection
```